# total issue with previous day

Tags: powerbi, dax

I calculate dayd over day. the measure returns correct values, but the total always 0 which is wrong, how to correct it ?

```
sales day over day = var _maxdate=CALCULATE(max('Date'[Date]), ALLSELECTED('Date'[Date]))
 var _mindate=CALCULATE(min('Date'[Date]), ALLSELECTED('Date'[Date]))
 var dates=filter(values('Date'[Date]), 'Date'[Date]<=_maxdate && 'Date'[Date]>=_mindate)
 return if(ISEMPTY('Date'), BLANK()
 
 , calculate(sum(Sales[Sales]), PREVIOUSDAY('Date'[Date]))+0)
```

I attach the pbix file https://1drv.ms/u/s!Amd7BXzYs7AVhBBCo_Ls7q5IkrXH?e=1ZQzsE
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with powerBI, but I suppose when column 'Date' is empty, blank() is returned but such value is not an illegible value to calculate 'total'. Try to remove these rows, or assuming an alternative date for that cases